# ERROR: could not form projection (LWPROJ) from 'srid=4326' to 'srid=2163'

Tags: postgis

Tried the following command but got error:

`ST_Transform(ST_SetSRID(ST_Point(lon , lat), 4326), 2163) As geom`

`ERROR:  could not form projection (LWPROJ) from 'srid=4326' to 'srid=2163'`

Runnning `postgis_full_version();` gives the following output

`POSTGIS="3.2.0 c3e3cc0" [EXTENSION] PGSQL="130" GEOS="3.10.1-CAPI-1.16.0" PROJ="6.3.1" LIBXML="2.9.10" LIBJSON="0.13.1" LIBPROTOBUF="1.3.3" WAGYU="0.5.0 (Internal)"`

Answer (score 3):

SRID-2163 is deprecated in later versions of GDAL
[Deprecated CRS (EPSG:2163) gets reinterpreted as another CRS (EPSG:9311) by GDAL](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/377099/deprecated-crs-epsg2163-gets-reinterpreted-as-another-crs-epsg9311-by-gdal).